# Android resource IDs are being incorrectly assigned

Tags: android, string, resources

I have encountered a strange problem where if I call `getString(R.string.somestringname)`, from time to time, even after deleting the R file and recompiling, the incorrect string appears. The emulator is not crashing and a valid string is appearing - it's just the wrong one.

A sample of my strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Activity Names -->
    <string name="app_name">an app name</string>
    <string name="selector_name">app name | Select</string>
    <string name="create">Create</string>
    <string name="overview_name">appname | Overview</string>
    <string name="another_name">appname | Another View</string> 

.....
    <!-- Edit Note -->
    <string name="placeholder">Foo bar</string> <-- here is a problem
    <string name="created">Created:</string>

</resources>
```

Here is a sample of code where one of the problems is encountered:

```
if (note.created != null) {
     createdtext.setText(getString(R.string.created) + " " + Util.longDateFormat(note.created));
}
```

The text that is output (*some of the time*) is `Foo bar November 03, 2010` (i.e. belonging to R.string.placeholder). What is going on? This is unnervingly making me tempted to hardcode the strings ;-)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I should probably mention my development environment is OSX Snow Leopard and I compile with 'ant install'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ant clean install` instead of just `ant install`.

Java inlines constants like the R.id values into generated bytecode, and sometimes your classes are not being recompiled, even though they need to be. Ideally, `ant install` would handle this properly; until it does, `ant clean install` is your friend.

Comment: im having problem with android studio, should i do gradlew clean?

Comment: @david: This particular problem (`R.id` values not matching their widgets) was more from the Ant/Eclipse realm. I have not seen this problem with Gradle (with or without Android Studio).

Comment: I have this problem every 2 - 3 builds android studio 2.1.1, maybe i misconfigured something in my app, but I dont think building android application will sometimes work and sometimes not (what i mean here is that it incorrectly assigned R.string. etc to mapped to wrong strings )